# Итератор для связанного списка

Tags: c++, list, итераторы

Требование преподавателя:

[image: Требование преподавателя]

Мне не понятно для чего нужна и, следовательно, как делать эту проверку.

Возникают такие вопросы:

Что делать если итератор смотрит на `null`? т.е. когда нет элемента на который смотрит итератор.

И что делать если следующий элемент `null`? т.е. когда нет следующего элемента.

Мой ответ: просто не доходить до `null`.

Для чего мне нужна проверка непонятно вот почему: есть ведь у меня в распоряжение первый и последний элемент списка, поэтому я могу в списке бегать не переходя границы. Для примера:

```
while (iter != list.end())
{
    iter++;
}
```

Итератор писался для двусвязного списка, т.е. элемент хранит значение `<type>` и ссылки на пред. и след. эл-ты, содержит простые логически операции, операторы `++`, `--`, `*`; конструктор/деструктор.

Comment: Сформулируй вопрос. Я не вижу вопроса. В чем твоя проблема?! Очевидно же, что если итератор указвыает на `end`, то значит список (или любой другой контейнер) "закончился".

Comment: Если ты сам пытаешься написать подобие итератора, то не (ин/де)крементируй указатель, если он достиг следующего после последнего, либо первого элемнта соответсвенно.

Comment: @Egorithm, от меня требую проверку на то, существуют ли элементы на который я смотрю и следующий за ним, ну вот проверил я, допустим, элемент на который смотрим или следующий - null, что теперь нужно сделать, как отреагировать на это, какой толк от такой проверки?

Comment: Вопросы такие к преподу. Чтобы проверить существует ли элемент в `std::list`, достаточно узнать размер контейнера методом `size()`. Итераторы не для того нужны.